# Should the "Insert an Image" popup re-use stack image links?

Tags: discussion, images

Currently if I click the Image icon in the post editor and paste in an image link such as https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmMXb.png that's actually hosted by SE it will still generate a new link, presumably downloading the image from its self, resulting in 2 copies being stored.

Should the image link be detected as being self-hosted and be used as is, without uploading a copy?

Comment: Stack Exchange does not host these images - imgur does; we just get a dedicated imgur server where the images are stored. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks. I guess my point remains though - images are copied to prevent them disappearing, but if the url is pointing to our image provider then there's no point copying it as it's already there.